# how can powerpoint addin get itself name?

Tags: vba, add-in, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint addin file named "abcde.ppam".
And I also add a "Auto_Open" Sub in order to run some code on PowerPoint Application startup.
My question is how can I get the name "abcde.ppam" in "Auto_Open"? 
Is the anything like "ThisAddin.name" or "ThisAddin.path" or any other workaround there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is declare a string constant in the add-in's code and set it to the name of the add-in.

Then you can do Application.Addins(MyName).Path and so on

Comment: thank you for answering the question. however what I want is the Addin itself name. If I already knew the addin's name is "MyName", I don't need anything else.

Comment: I don't understand the problem them.  Surely you know the name of the add-in as you're writing it. Assign the name to a constant as I suggested and the add-in will know its own name.

Comment: Just want to know how can an Addin refer itself while don't know its name?

Comment: Unless you do as I've suggested, requiring one line of code, it cant'.

Comment: But if a user renames the add-in, `MyName` is no longer the add-in's name.

Comment: Interesting ... I wonder when they changed that.  For a long time, in the Windows version, the add-in name was the name you set in Tools | Project Properties; it was always the file name on Mac PPT.  But now?  You're right.  They've gone and Mac-ed it.  Arrghh.

Answer (score 1):

OK, how about this approach. You'd want to rename WhoAmIToday to something that's unique per add-in.  WhoMe_{guid} or the like.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sFilename As String

    ' Get the internal name of the add-in
    sTemp = WhoAmIToday

    For x = 1 To Application.AddIns.Count
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Attempt to call the same WhoAmI routine on each addin in the addins collection
        If Application.Run(Application.AddIns(x).Name & "!WhoAmIToday") = sTemp Then
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                ' Found it; here's the name
                MsgBox Application.AddIns(x).Name
            End If
        End If

    Next

End Sub

Function WhoAmIToday() As String
   WhoAmIToday = "Yes. It's ME"
End Function
```

Comment: unique id can be generated in Auto_Open so several copies of the same .ppam have different ids https://gist.github.com/Winand/5e34529df029baa87b70b6abd0c51d92

Comment: @Winand Interesting idea and a neat solution to OP's question, I think.  One drawback is that it wouldn't help if external code is trying to locate an add-in within an instance of PPT, since it'd have no way of knowing the randomly generated id in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well Steve, I've got to correct you. You can identify an addin by calling a unique function you build into your addin.  If it is there, you know that this is the very addin even though a user may have renamed the file. Roughly

```
sub getMe()
dim MyAddin as addin
dim oAddin as addin
for each oAddin in application.addins
on error resume next
if (application.run ....uniqueFunction) = "YepItsMe" then
 Set MyAddin = oAddin
 exit for
end if
err.clear
next

'....code acting upon MyAddin

end sub

function uniqueFunction() as string
uniqueFunction="YepItsMe"
end function
```

Comment: How does changing `oAddin` affect the line `if (application.run ....uniqueFunction) = "YepItsMe" then`?

Comment: The add-in may know the value of `uniqueFunction`, but it won't know its actual name or its path. And your code will set `myAddIn` to the first add-in in the list, not to the actual add-in.