# Get name of the VBA Add-in file running THIS code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I have VBA code providing some metadata and file utilities ... to be distributed to a lot of users ... and I have ported it to Excel (MyAddIn.xlam), Powerpoint (MyAddIn.ppam) and Word (MyAddIn.dotm). All is working well so far on Office 2010/13/17 and 365. Now ... for some good reason I need to determine the name and location of the AddIn file running the code.

In Excel I can use

```
MYPROGFILE = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
```

If the above code is run from MyAddIn.xlam I get exactly this, even though my active workbook is "MyDatafile.xlsm"

In Powerpoint and Word there are no "This..." type of objects which would give me the name of the file running the code. The best I came up with so far is

```
Dim Myself As AddIn
For Each Myself In AddIns
    If Myself.Name = "MyAddIn" Then ' PPT port
    ' If Myself.Name = "MyAddIn.dotm" Then ' Word port
        MYPROGFILE = Myself.FullName ' PPT port
        ' MYPROGFILE = Myself.Path & "\" & Myself.Name ' Word port
        Exit For
    End If
Next Myself
```

which I utterly dislike because

1. I have to hardcode the addin name
2. I have to be absolutely sure that the name under which the add-in is saved is the hardcoded one, and no user ever renames it (which is out of my control)
3. Powerpoint wants the name without extension, Word wants a ".dotm" added which increases complexity of ports

Can anyone imagine a better solution than this ugly loop and hardcoded name ... something closer to what is possible in Excel?

Comment: It is only PowerPoint that doesn't have a "This..". Word has "ThisDocument"

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918464/how-can-powerpoint-addin-get-itself-name